# Index cond did not appear in postgres query plan

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I am reading this [article](http://postgresguide.com/performance/explain.html#what-is-an-execution-plan), and decided to try example on my own.

**Before adding index:**

I have table `BookHibernate`, sql was generated by `hibernate`:

```
CREATE TABLE bookhibernate
(
  book_id bigint NOT NULL,
  bought boolean,
  genre character varying(255),
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  price integer NOT NULL,
  author_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT bookhibernate_pkey PRIMARY KEY (book_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_hlepqn9vy6biuo6vn47jo5ewx FOREIGN KEY (book_id)
      REFERENCES authorhibernate (author_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_r9o6704wcbcawmruyqojj4nab FOREIGN KEY (author_id)
      REFERENCES authorhibernate (author_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

So I called `explain analyze`:

```
explain analyze select * from bookhibernate where bookhibernate.price > 10
```

It gives me:

```
"Seq Scan on bookhibernate  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=1 width=1053) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=2 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (price > 10)"
"Planning time: 0.054 ms"
"Execution time: 0.021 ms"
```

**After adding index:**

```
create index my_index on bookhibernate(price);
```

After adding index and executing same `explain analyze` i see that `execution plan` didn't change and I see `Filter: (price > 10)` register, but I expected to see `Index cond: (price > 10)`.

Why does my expectation fail?

**UPDATED:**

I was told that it because small table size. It sounds reasonable, and it's true. But I tried my query against 1000 rows table.

1. Why does `Postgres` decide to use Filtering? Why is it preferable?
2. What is the behind the scene of `Filter: (price > 10)`? What is the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: Is there any data in your table? Did you run `analyze` on the table?

Comment: @jmelesky, yes, two rows / yes

Comment: For two rows, no database will ever use an index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I updated my question. thanks!

Comment: How many rows are removed by the condition? Add the execution plan using `explain (analyze, verbose) select ...` for the table with 1000 rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I tried both: remove small amount and big - nothing changes.`Rows Removed by Filter:`  From 10 to 700

Comment: [Quoted from the site you are reading](http://postgresguide.com/performance/indexes.html#indexes-in-action):  "*It is not always fastest for Postgres to make use of an index. Most of the time you should trust Postgres to do the right thing. An example case is when your query returns a large percentage of the data that exists in a table, it may not use the index. This is because it is easiest to scan the table once, versus using the index then making additional lookups*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table size is so small that it is more efficient for PostgreSQL to perform a sequential scan than to use the index. If you want PostgreSQL to consider an index at all, add more rows to the table.

Not only the table size, but also the selectivity of the condition influences the optimizer's decision whether to use an index or not.
If many books have a `price` greater than 10, it is less efficient to use an index scan because that involves random I/O (the index pages are not stored on disk sequentially). In that case an sequential scan is always more efficient.

There are several PostgreSQL configuration parameters that influence how likely PostgreSQL is to choose an index, the most important being `random_page_cost`.

You can test if your index is eligible by setting `enable_seqscan = off` and then running your `EXPLAIN` query again.
With this setting, PostgreSQL will use an index scan if it is possible at all.

Comment: Thanks, I see the point. I tried to run query against 1000 rows and `Postgres` decided that it better to filter then to use binary search with index. Why does it happened? When index algorithm is `lg(n)` what is an algorithm complexity for  `Filter: (price > 10)`?

Comment: I have improved the answer. Selecting a single index entry is `O(ln(n))`, but scanning a relevant portion of the index is not.